# Is there any better way to pass function to props with LitElement?

Tags: polymer, lit-element

I'm using polymer LitElement and i tried to pass a function to props but did'nt work, this is the way i found to work, but its awfull... Any better suggestions?

```
import { LitElement, html, customElement, property } from 'lit-element';

@customElement('my-element')
export class MyElement extends LitElement {


onButtonClick = function name (){

  console.log("Clicked!!")
}

  render() {
    return html`

      <c-button text="Button Name" onClick="${this.onButtonClick}" />
    `;
  }
}

@customElement("c-button")
export class CButton extends LitElement{

  @property() text;
  @property() onClick;

  handleClick(){
    let fct = eval(`( ${this.onClick} )` )
    fct();
  }

  render(){
    return html`

      <button @click="${this.handleClick}" > ${this.text} </button> 
    `
  }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By default lit-html [data bindings](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/template-reference#binding-types) set an attribute which means it'll have to convert the value to a string.

Instead of `onClick="${this.onButtonClick}"` prefix it with `.` like this `.onClick="${this.onButtonClick}"`. That will set a property in JavaScript instead and the method will be passed by reference.

Answer (score 4):

@abraham's answer is good for the general case: you can set properties, including functions, with the `.` syntax.

However, if you're specifically dealing with events, then I would use event bindings (`@` syntax) and make sure the the event you're interested in is either bubbling and composed (as `click` is) so that it'll propagate out of the child component, or re-dispatched by the child component. Events are a good model, I'd use them for event-like things.